# What is the best way to implement Lambda-architecture batch_layer and serving_layer?

Tags: lambda-architecture

If I am build a project applying Lambda-architecture now, should I split the batch layer and the serving layer, i.e. program A do the batch layer's work, program B do the serving layer's? they are physically independent but logically relevant, since program A can tell B to work after A finishes the pre-compute works.

If so, would you please tell me how to implement it? I am thinking about IPC. If IPC could help, what is the specific way?

BTW, what does "batch view" mean exactly? why and How does the serving layer index it?

Comment: A batch view is a subset of the batch layer which holds queries to the masterset. When you do a general query, what are you really doing is querying the corresponding batch views (from the serving layer) and speed layer views (from the speed layer, obviously). The batch layer is a general formalization of the masterset you declared, which holds the entire stored data.

Answer (score 3):

What is the best way to implement Lambda Architecture batch_layer and serving_layer?  That totally depends upon the specific requirements, system environment, and so on.  I can address how to design Lambda Architecture batch_layer and serving_layer, though.

Incidentally, I was just discussing this with a colleague yesterday and this is based on that discussion.  I will explain in 3 parts and for the sake of this discussion lets say we are interested in designing a system that computes the most read stories (a) of the day, (b) of the week, (c) of the year:

Firstly in a lambda architecture, it is important to divide the problem that you are trying to solve with respect to time first and features second.  So if you model your data as an incoming stream then the speed layer deals with the 'head' of the stream, e.g. current day's data; the batch layer deals with the 'head' + 'tail', the masterset.

Secondly, divide the features between these time-based lines.  For instance, some features can be done using the 'head' of the stream alone, while other features require a wider breadth of data than the 'head', e.g. masterset.  In our example, lets say that we define the speed layer to compute one day's worth of data.  Then the Speed layer would compute most read stories (a) of the day in the so-called Speed View; while the Batch Layer would compute most read stories (a) of the days, (b) of the week, and (c) of the year in the so-called Batch View.  Note that yes there may appear to be a bit of redundancy but hold on to that thought.

Thirdly, serving layer response to queries from clients regarding Speed View and Batch View and merges results accordingly.  There will necessarily be overlap in the results from the Speed View and the Batch View.  No matter, this is divide of Speed vs Batch, among other benefits, allows us to minimize exposure to risks such as (1) rolling out bugs, (2) corrupt data delivery, (3) long-running batch processes, etc.  Ideally, issues will be caught in the speed view and then fixes will be applied prior to the batch view re-compute.  If it is then all is well and good.

In summary, no IPC needs to be used since they are completely independent from each other.  So program A does not need to communicate to program B.  Instead, the system relies upon some overlap of processing.  For instance, if program B computes its Batch view based on a daily basis then program A needs to compute the Speed view for day plus any additional time that processing may take.  This extra time needs to include any downtime in the batch layer.

Hope this helps!

Notes:

- Redundancy of the batch layer - it is necessary to have at least some redundancy in the batch layer since the serving layer must be able to provide a single cohesive view of results to queries.  At the least, the redundancy may help avoid time-gaps in query responses.
- Assessing which features are in the speed layer - this step will not always be as convenient as in the 'most read stories' example here.  This is more of an art form.